# Migrate Struts application from JBoss server 4.3 to 7.1

Tags: struts2, jboss7.x, application-server

I have a Struts web application which I want to migrate from JBoss server 4.3 to JBoss 7.1.

Can anyone tell me what things do I need to consider while migrating application to newer version like connection pooling, EJB compatibility, etc., which is dependent on JBoss server?

Answer (score 0):

Since jboss 7 changed their class loading scheme you at first place consider to configure the class path to include only required libraries not loaded by the server.  Everything else should be fixed separately because Struts framework doesn't have a reference to relayed problems.